# Use of undeclared type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'

Tags: swift, xcode, archive, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to send an update to an application built in Xcode 7, Swift 2.3. The application builds and runs fine with no issues, however, when I attempt to Archive I receive "Use of undeclared type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'".

I figured it was just my old project giving me grief so I created a new project which had one class:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {}
```

Again, it works when building and gives me **the same error** when archiving. I am currently using Xcode 8.0, any ideas??

Comment: Check that in Link Binary with Libraries, `MessageUI.framework` is added.